# Cant use replication from SQL Server 2008 to Sybase?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, replication, sybase, database-replication

Weve upgraded from SQL Server 2000 to SQL Server 2008.
Our DBA now tells us it's not possible to replicate tables from SQL Server 2008 to Sybase (12.5).

Is this correct? If not whats the best approach?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replication from sybase ASE to SQL server enterprise edition is possible only when SQL server is acting as publisher and sybase as subscriber. This is using Microsoft SQL server replication.

However for using sybase replication, please refer to 
  http://www.sybase.com/detail?id=1024758 
 http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wwerner1/archive/2011/06/08/replication-sql-server-to-sybase.aspx 
(I am afraid the above link was last updated in 2003, so beware and check Sybase support)

Or another option is to create a linker server between sybase server and SQL server and track changes in the source using left outer joins on the tables, merge etc., and then applying the same to destination DB and scheduling this as part of sql job agent.